# Creating a custom style for Javascript's Confirm Function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to custom style the  javascript's "Confirm Function" dialog box, instead of using the the default look and feel that is provided by the browser?  If not is there an alternative solution to this?

Comment: there are few jQuery plugins that can you use..

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, is there any jquery plugin you could should suggest @DipeshParmar? **Thanks in advance**

Comment: search for custom alert box jquery in google....i mostly used is jAlert

Answer (score 1):

if you want to custom look for confirm box , you need to use jalert javascript for that.
check link below hope it will help you.

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 0):

you can not style javascript "confirm function" dialog box because its default option if you want to do the same then you have to create your own dialog box with the help of Javascript/jQuery and CSS

E.g. http://demos.9lessons.info/alert_delete.html